# Google Sheets: Average percentage using multiple conditions

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I would like to get an average percentage out of my sample, however, I need to use several conditions. I tried to use the `AVERAGE` and `AVERAGEIF` together with `FILTER` but everything returns an error and I think I'm incorrectly "merging" formulas.

You can find [my test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LEU7TntqKCf16D8qVlKGrPnN4ouUOjmddNve7YgcfRg/edit?usp=sharing) here.

The rules I need to apply:

1. The score for individual rows is possible to find in the "Data" sheet in cell N and the total results should be visible in the sheet "Calculation" cell E.
2. As the sample is huge in real life, I need to filter out several pieces of information and add conditions:

- to filter out all items where the code/ID starts with 0: `Data!A:A&"", "^0.+"`
- to filter out all items that are matching the date in the Calculation sheet: `Data!C:C=$B3`
- to filter all items with the specific name:  `Data!B:B=$A3`

Any idea how to get the average % out of items with specific filters?

---

**UPDATE**

Expected results: I want to see the total average for a specific date, name, and ID, and let's say I would use these filters, then I would see only the final average percentage.

1. Test =100%
2. Test = 0%
3. Test = 100%

Total Average %: **66.7%**

Also, I think the best way would be to use AVERAGEIFS, but I'm getting the error "Array arguments to AVERAGEIFS are of different size".

```
=AVERAGEIFS(Data!N:N,Data!B:B=$A3,Data!C:C=$B3,Data!A:A&"", "^0.+")
```

Comment: What do you mean by average percentage? I think I'm following what you want to do, generally, but I'm a bit confused on what you want the end result to be. Would it be possible to add a sheet to that document to demonstrate the expected result?

Comment: @kaitlynmm569 I added the example of what I mean in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS(Data!N3:N,Data!B3:B,A3,Data!C3:C,B3,ARRAYFORMULA(if(LEN(Data!A3:A),REGEXMATCH(Data!A3:A,"^0.+"),"")),TRUE),"")
```

[image]

or

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(FILTER(Data!N3:N,Data!B3:B=A3,Data!C3:C=B3,REGEXMATCH(Data!A3:A,"^0.+"))),"")
```

[image]

or

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(QUERY({Data!A3:C,Data!N3:N},"select avg(Col4) where Col1 starts with '0' and Col2 = '"&A3&"' and Col3 = '"&B3&"'"),2,0),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works in the test sheet, however, when reproducing formulas in the real sheet I'm receiving the error "Evaluation of function AVERAGE caused a divide by zero error." I removed the "if error" part to troubleshoot where is the problem as all of the values returned blank. Any idea how to get rid of the error and get the value?

Comment: Hard to tell, but the `divide by zero` means you've no results in the filtered outcome. Try using `=FILTER(Data!N3:N,Data!B3:B=A3,Data!C3:C=B3,REGEXMATCH(Data!A3:A,"^0.+"))` and each time, you leave one of the conditions out of the filter to find out the reason. If the outcome is indeed empty, the iferror handles the `divide by zero` error.

Comment: Also make sure all the columns in your source table and summary table which you want to compare are formatted the same (dates as dates, text as text, percentages as percentages,...)

Comment: @Devat Can you provide a dataset in which this error is thrown?

Comment: @W.S. I was thinking about the same and I find out where is the problem, therefore, I will ask another question here on Stack. I accepted your answer as it resolved the issue. Thanks!